# RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Command.__call__' was never awaited

Tags: discord.py

I'm making a discord bot in discord.py. I got a warning message in console and i don't know what to do with this.

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Command.__call__' was never awaited
  print(f"Bot is online {client.user}")
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name=f"{len(client.guilds)} server | >help"))
    print(f"Bot is online {client.user}")
```

Answer (score 0):

There's literally nothing wrong with your code. I just tried it and it runs OK.
Maybe try restarting your command-line or reinstalling (pip) discord.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intent = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Client(command_prefix = '*', intents = intent)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name=f"{len(client.guilds)} server | >help"))
    print(f"Bot is online {bot.user}")

client.run('IAUHSDIFHoihaosdfha1234.G_GuRg.RdalU8if2MiSDNDt1Ybb0jAv23RgluAGab4iuI')
```

[image: Evd 1]

PS.: Invalid token above, just an example.